# SQLite select from table based on other table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables, one is a list of companies and the other a list of products.
The products are linked to a company in the column 'company_id'

To better understand, this is what I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE company_id = (Company.id where name = Google)
```

What would be the correct way of writing this statement?

Comment: `... = (SELECT companies.id FROM companies WHERE name = 'Google'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write it either as a subselect

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE company_id =(SELECT id FROM companies WHERE name = 'Google' limit 1)
```

Or with subselect with in() operator

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE company_id in (SELECT id FROM companies WHERE name = 'Google')
```

Or write it as a join

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM Products p
inner join companies c on p.company_id=c.id
WHERE c.name='Google'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and simple answer!